# Why is one of my `Global.asax.cs` file in my ASP.net solution with two startup projects not called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

In a Visual Studio (Professional 2017) *solution*, I have multiple *projects*, two of which are startup projects, the `UI` and the `API`. The curious thing is that the `API\Global.asax.cs` does not seem to be executed, although both startup projects are actually enabled to be launched for debugging. I am sure about that, since when hitting the green *Debug* arrow, two browser windows open, and both UI and API work.

There are two distinct `Global.asax.cs`-files, one for each startup project (whether that is a sensible design, I don't know - I took over the solution this way). Within the one for the API, breakpoints are not working, more specifically VS says:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A copy of Global.asax.cs was found in UI.dll, but the current source code is different from the version built into UI.dll.
>
> To allow this breakpoint to be hit: right-click on the breakpoint, choose either 'Conditions...' or 'Setting...'. Then chcoose 'Location', 'Allow the source code to be different from the original.'
>
> To allow this for all breakpoints, disable the option 'Required source files to exactly match the original version' under Tools, Options, Debugging, General.

The full hover-over-breakpoint-message looks as follows:
[image: full error message screen shot]

Following the last suggestion did not change anything. Concerning the first suggestion, I do not have the options to choose in the context menu under `Conditions`.

I cannot inquire to much about the solutions's architectural background, that is why I am
asking here for help: I am assuming that the error message also means that the file `API/Global.asax.cs` is not read at all, or is that conclusion wrong?

More importantly: **How do I ensure that `API\Global.asax.cs` is read/ executed?**
Differently put: When is it supposed to be executed when in debug mode? I have the impression, it executed every now and then since I see debug-output in my VS-*Output* window sometimes - I did not manage to guess when it is executed.

#### Edit: Further Background

In in the **Solution Property Pages** (right-click on the solution and choose **Properties**), there is the option **Multiple startup projects** chosen. The `API` project is in the list before `UI`.

Under **Project Dependency** is specified that the `API` project depends on different other projects, but not the `UI` project. The other projects have some inter-dependencies as well, but none of them depends on the `UI` project. The `UI` project does not depend on any other project, either.

#### References

- [Why would my ASP.NET project run on the development server when not among the startup projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482012/why-would-my-asp-net-project-run-on-the-development-server-when-not-among-the-st)
- [Where does the output of System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine go, if I put it in Global.asax.cs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750065/where-does-the-output-of-system-diagnostics-debug-writeline-go-if-i-put-it-in-g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any one ASP.NET web app there can be only one `Global.asax` file (whether with code behind or not). One of the `Global.asax` files will be overwriting the other if both projects deployed to the same folder, and the one that wins will specify the winning start up type that hooks into the `Application` instance's events:

```
 <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyProject.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

The only way to have two would be two separate web apps (one could be in a child folder, providing it is – in IIS – set as a web app of its own and thus running it its own AppDomain if in the same IIS App Pool or otherwise in its own process).

Comment: For me, one`Global.asax` is in `API/`, the other in the subfolder `UI/`, no one is in the main folder, so it is not immediately clear which is the parent. I have the impression that the UI-one wins since it the one started second. Does that make sense? Where and how do I specify the parent if I cannot move the two files (I was told, I am not allowed to move them)?

Comment: Are the two folders just folders/virtual directories in IIS, or separate web apps. pulling the `global.asax` anywhere other than the root of the web app isn't normal.

Comment: I guess I am not familiar with the exact definition of Web App in this context (I assume it is different from VS project). In my main folder of the solution, I have the solution file `*.sln` (and `packages.lock.json`), then there are several folders for the projects. For deploying, we end up with two folders only, one for each startup project.

Comment: If it helps, the API is fully C#, the UI is in React. Both folders have their own `favicon.ico`. The `UI/global.asax` is mainly empty, except for a `protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {           RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);  }` - the one of the API has quite some stuff inside `Application_Start()`.

Comment: So when deployed, each is in a separate folder, inside the same parent?  Does that parent contain anything asp.net related?  or its parent?  How are these set up in IIS?  Is one nested inside the other?  Inside a common parent?  Is that parent an asp.net thing?

Comment: @Amy: When deployed, there are two different folders `UI` and `API`, same parent, but in the parent is nothing else than the two folder. Concerning the IIS-setup - what do you refer to? What should I check?

Comment: Please note my edit on the project dependency in the question. I assume that I have two web-apps, the `API` and the `UI`. Do you agree?

Comment: IIS has its concept of an App that is significant here (hence needing to know that). I learnt in the days before IIS Express which hides many details from devs until the point of deployment. For something else please ask a new question (the purpose of [SO] is for others to be able to find solutions to their similar problems).